# Tough str_replace, replace parts of result from sql

Tags: php, sql, str-replace

I am trying to pull data from an sql table and make it so images will display. I have images for each value in the table.

RAW Data from the database:

```
["NVGoggles"|"ItemMap"|"ItemCompass"|"ItemWatch"|"ACE_CharliePack_ACU_Medic"|"Binocular"|"ACRE_PRC148_ID_2"|"ACRE_PRC343_ID_7"|"CZ805_B_GL_ACR"]
```

It is an Inventory from a game.

I want to make it so each item will be an image.

I have tried this:

```
$wea = str_replace('["', '<img src="admin/images/thumbs/', $row["wea"]) & str_replace('"|"', '.png</img><br><img src="admin/images/thumbs/', $row["wea"]) & str_replace('"]', '.png</img>', $row["wea"]);
```

and I have tried

```
$wea = str_replace('["', '<img src="admin/images/thumbs/', $row["wea"]);
$wea2 = str_replace('"|"', '.png</img><br><img src="admin/images/thumbs/', $wea);
$wea3 = str_replace('"]', '.png</img>', $wea2);
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: `explode('"|"', trim($str, ' []'))`

Comment: but I am trying to replace them with starting <i>mg tags, closing </img> tags and a <br /> after each image.

I have 1,106 images that I have named the same as the items in the raw data. I need to make each one a .png image.

Comment: Btw, you should really normalise your database ;-)

Comment: @Jack I wish I could. The system that saves this data from the game to the database is made by a different dev than the game dev or my self. There for it is how it is set on everyone's servers so I need to make it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said you can get items as an array with:

```
explode('"|"', trim($str, ' []'))
```

But if you want your way, then proper code would be:

```
$wea = str_replace('["', '<img src="admin/images/thumbs/', $row["wea"]);
$wea2 = str_replace('"|"', '.png" /><br><img src="admin/images/thumbs/', $wea);
$wea3 = str_replace('"]', '.png" />', $wea2);
```

as a proper html `img` tag is:

```
<img src="admin/images/thumbs/file.jpg" />
```

Also `str_replace` can replace multiple values in one call:

```
$wea = str_replace(
    array('["', '"|"', '"]'),
    array(
        '<img src="admin/images/thumbs/',
        '.png" /><br><img src="admin/images/thumbs/',
        '.png" />',
    ),
    $row['wea']
);
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you, Sorry I been up for (going on 39 hours) working on this. Is that all I messed up is the img tag?

PS: Thank you so much! I would +1 but I need 2 rep before I can.

Answer (score 4):

It almost looks like JSON encoding, so you could apply a little trick to turn it into an array:

```
$items = json_decode(strtr($row["wea"], '|', ','), true);
$result = array_map(function($item) { 
    return sprintf('<img src="admin/images/thumbs/%s.png">', $item);
}, $items);
```